# raw_input for Subject line [python smtp]

Tags: python, email, smtplib

I need to have 'cid' in this script as the subject line in an email. It can't just be in the message body or header, but the actual subject line in the recipient's inbox

```
import smtplib

cid = raw_input()
cmd = #output from a script

to = 'my@email.com'
m_login = 'recipient@email.com'
m_pwd = 'mypassword'
header = 'To:' + to + '\n' + 'From:' + m_login + '\n' + '\n'

smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.outgoingserver.com",587)
smtpserver.ehlo()
smtpserver.ehlo
smtpserver.login(m_login, m_pwd)
mail = header + cmd     
smtpserver.sendmail(m_login, to, mail)
smtpserver.close()
```

Comment: no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Can you edit this question to clarify what you're after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Subject:` header *is* what's displayed in the recipient's inbox. So your stipulation that this *not* be in the headers makes no sense at all. Just add it to your headers, e.g.:

```
header = 'To: %s\nFrom: %s\nSubject: %s\n\n' % (to, m_login, cid)
```

Comment: I'll try this again, but when I had `Subject` in my header before it only appeared in the message body.

Comment: If it's appearing in the message body, it's not in the header.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd guess that originally you put it at the end of what you originally had there, and the `\n\n` (which ends the header) therefore came before the subject line. A good way to avoid that kind of problem is to define the headers as a list of strings and then use `'\n'.join(headers) + '\n\n' + body` to join the header with the body for sending. That way you don't worry about the line endings when defining the headers.